# Fiddler not displaying sessions

Tags: fiddler

I've got the latest version of fiddler installed on 2 machines (v2.3.0), and on one machine it displays web sessions, and in the other it doesn't.

This is using IE and Firefox on Win7.

I have tried deleting my customrules.js and letting fiddler create a new one.

I know that the broken machine is indeed proxying traffic through fiddler, as I see the fiddler SSL cert when I go to HTTPS sites.

I have set the option at the bottom-left of the window to All Processes, Web Browser and Non-Browser to no avail. I just can't seem to get the sessions to display.

Any hints to where I should look to find out what's going wrong?

Thanks,

Kirk

Comment: Thanks Chris, Eric - it was the Filters tab I had messed up. Cheers!

Answer (score 49, accepted):

In rough order of likelihood..

- Ensure `File->Capture Traffic` is checked (obviously).
- Ensure it says "All Processes" in the bottom left.
- Flick to the "Filters" tab and uncheck `Use Filters` (I *always* forget this..)
- Same goes for the "AutoResponder" tab.
- Click the "Process Filter" button on the toolbar once to make sure it's off.
- Go to `Help->About Fiddler` and compare the port number with `IE->Options->Connections->Lan settings->Proxy server->Advanced`
- If that fails, uncheck the following:

  ```
  Rules->Hide Image Requests
  Rules->Hide HTTPS Connects
  Rules->Hide 304s
  ```
- To eliminate anything in the rules script, go to `Rules->Customize Rules` and add the following line to the end of `OnBeforeResponse()`:

  ```
  oSession.oFlags.Remove("ui-hide");
  ```

  (If that fixes it, something in your rules is setting `oSession["ui-hide"]`)

After these steps its time to think 'applicatin specific'.  For example .net won't proxy for "localhost".  [This page](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler/help/hookup.asp) has application specific tips, such as  PHP, .net, Java,  Win 7 phone,etc..

If all that fails, go to the [Fiddler group](http://groups.google.com/group/httpfiddler) and post a question, you'll normally get a pretty quick response from Eric Lawrence himself.

simple..

Comment: +1 for 'Rules-> Hide Image Requests' to remedy my own problem - I had kept thinking that should be under Filters somewhere, but it wasn't.

Comment: "Internet Explorer and the .NET Framework are hardcoded not to send requests for Localhost through any proxies, and as a proxy, Fiddler will not receive such traffic." That was causing my problem. Solved it by putting localhost2 assigned to 127.0.0.1 in my windows hosts file.  Hope that helps anyone still looking.

Comment: Surprisingly, Chrome is not recognized as a browser by Fiddler. I had to activate "All Processes" options for getting HTTPS through Chrome decrypted.

Comment: I had a similar problem and the solution was to make sure the supported protocols was correct. I had included all of them, assuming it would pick the best one. It wasn't until I reduced my protocols to `ssl3;tls1.1;tls1.2`, did it start working. Just something to add to your list ;-)

Comment: @UpHelix thanks. i'm on a network, so connecting through my network ip did the trick

Answer (score 4):

http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler/help/faq.asp

Set the Status bar filter to "All Processes", check that the Process Filter in the toolbar isn't set, and examine the Filters tab to make sure that no rules are enabled. If you've written or set any Rules (see the menu) check those too.

Answer (score 1):

If the other answers don't work, right click on fiddler and select "Run as Administrator".

Comment: This was my issue when I was getting no traffic from a C++ app using MFC CInternetFile and CHTTPFile classes.  

Ran as admin and I started to see traffic.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this problem as well and as mentioned before it can happen because of the proxy server.

For me the problem was I was using a VPN Proxy Extension, such as Hola or Unblock Youku. So I simply turned them off.

Comment: Same here, it took a while to figure out that all I had to do was disable my company VPN....

Answer (score 0):

Simply try out this

```
Help -> Troubleshoot Filters
```

And also  click the 'Filters' tab and either uncheck Use Filters or modify the filter appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same issue and resolved it by ending all Fiddler processes in Task Manager by checking the Show processes from all users. Another user on the machine I use(loaner) still had a Fiddler session going. Ending that session and beginning a new one seems to have fixed the problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

this worked for me but uncheck Troubleshoot not showing any sessions to me
i have no filter no rule
any process checked
all sessions checked

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the WebSessions window's (left window) size was very small. I dragged it out to an appropriate size, which fixed the issue.