# How to capture the network traffic using java script and change the url of the JS on the fly

Tags: javascript, javascript-debugger, network-traffic

Problem is, in production we cannot debug the JS code as it is minified/compressed.

I want to debug the un compressed javascript.

The url of the js for minified/compressed and un compressed will be as follows.

compressed : https://hostname/appname/compressed/testjs.js

Uncompressed : https://hostname/appname/uncompressed/testjs.js

Since i know the URL of uncompressed, i want to replace the URL with the compressed URL.

This can be achieved through Fiddler AutoResponder feature ([How can I debug a minified JS in firebug?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5386826/how-can-i-debug-a-minified-js-in-firebug))

But i don't want to use third party tools because we need to login to production and customers will not accept to install the tools.

Is there any we can capture the JS url requests and replace the url.

Comment: Use prettify or source maps.

Comment: Check if web worker can do this..

Comment: Maybe this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Service_Worker_API

Comment: Also: https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/service-workers/