# Why didn't Fiddler show this activity?

Tags: fiddler

We have a Client Toolkit provided by our partner that allows us to access their web services. It started giving errors yesterday on any call and initially their support wanted us to provide a Fiddler log. I tried to do so, however there was no activity shown in Fiddler when the call was made.

From this I would have assumed that the error would have to have occurred before an actual web request was sent out. However, the issue turned out to be an update they did that requires an SSL connection. They rolled back the change but advised us to update our calls to use https so they can re-implement their update.

So if the change was on their end, that means that communications obviously were going on with their server. Why wouldn't that have shown up in Fiddler? Are there scenarios where communications occur but a request isn't fully created or something like that? I just assumed that if there was any communication whatsoever that "something" would show up in Fiddler.

Comment: [This similar question/answer may provide you some things to check...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3444352/fiddler-not-displaying-sessions)

Comment: Windows can only capture session from programs that use the Windows proxy settings. Programs that does not query the Windows proxy settings and use the direct connection are not redirected through Fiddler.

Comment: @Robert They asked for the Fiddler log, so I would have to assume the traffic would normally show up in Fiddler (otherwise why would this be a normal way for them to troubleshoot?). And generally speaking, I could be wrong but, I think any WebRequest coming from asp.net would show up in Fiddler.